# Erro ao buscar vídeo pela localização no Youtube Api V3

Tags: url, youtube-api

Gostaria de saber qual é o erro da URL:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&location=-12.2582688%252C-38.9442314&maxResults=10&order=date&type=video&_h=6&

Sempre que coloco a latitude e longitude do local que quero dá erro na requisição:

```
500 Internal Server Error
{
   "error": {
      "code": 500,
      "message": null
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acrescente um raio de ação, senão *acho* que ele só procura pela coordenada exata. Aqui, sua mesma consulta com `locationRadius` de `5km`:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&location=-12.2582688%252C-38.9442314&locationRadius=5km&maxResults=10&order=date&type=video&_h=1&

Segundo a documentação (minha ênfase):

> O `locationRadius`, ***em conjunto*** com o parametro `location`, define a área geográfica. Se as coordenadas associadas com o vídeo caem dentro dessa área, então o vídeo pode ser incluído nos resultados da busca.

Comment: Resolve mas não justifica! Nada indica que o raio de ação é obrigatório! +1

Comment: não tenho certeza @Zuul, a documentação parece indicar que é necessário... creio que minha interpretação da coordenada exata é correta

Comment: Ok, encontrei a [documentação da API V2](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#locationsp) onde claramente diz que um depende do outro. Na documentação da V3 o Inglês deles está mal traduzido e não é claro o suficiente ;) (Podes editar a resposta e afirmar a mesma, tá correto o que falaste)

Comment: Coloquei 1 metro na requisição e retorna 9 resultados, deve ser o mais exato possível. Valeu por confirmar, @Z